# Know if a record was just inserted via C# 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, executenonquery

Is it possible in **C# / ASP.NET** to know if the `ExecuteNonQuery` inserted a record or not?

I am checking to make sure the email address does not exist in the table using a subquery.

**Is there a way to know if an Insert was made in ASP.NET?**

```
CommandPrizeEmails.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
CommandPrizeEmails.Parameters.Add("@DateToday", SqlDbType.DateTime);

CommandPrizeEmails.Parameters["@Email"].Value = txtEmail.Text;
CommandPrizeEmails.Parameters["@DateToday"].Value = DateTime.Now;

CommandPrizeEmails.ExecuteNonQuery();

//int newID = (int)CommandPrizeEmails.ExecuteScalar();

//CommandPrizeEmails.ExecuteNonQuery();
//if (newID >= 1) {
//    divSuccesfulEntry.Visible = true;
//} else {
//    divRepeatEntry.Visible = true;
//}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the `ExecuteScalar()`?  If i'm not mistaken, it should return the number of rows affected by the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the rows affected in return to verify the process.

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command.
>
> When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return
>   value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or
>   update operation and the number of
>
> rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/01/27/sqlcommand-executenonquery-returns-1-when-doing-insert-update-delete.aspx

Comment: Does `int retVal = CommandPrizeEmails.ExecuteNonQuery();` do BOTH an Insert (if possible) AND set a `retVal`? ... My Insert is not working for a fresh email addie.

Comment: yeah... if your sql query works fine it will insert & return retVal the no of row effected. And you can check retVal for finding whether it works or not

Comment: Thank you but I must be doing something wrong. I am not getting an Insert. Does this REQUIRE I use a SP?  I really don't need a SP here.. Thanks.

Comment: For insert you have to either use sp or any direct query depends.. nothing wrong to use sp. First try your SP is working in sql directly excute there.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my subquery. Do you know what it may be? `INSERT INTO Emails (email, insertDate) VALUES (@Email, @DateToday) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Emails.email FROM Emails WHERE Emails.email = @Email);"`

Comment: I am using MS SQL SERVER

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteNonQuery Return Boolean value catch value

ex:

```
bool flg;

flg=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
if (flg)
{ msgbox("successfully inserted");}
else {msgbox("not inserted");}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bool flg;

flg=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
if (flg)
{ MessageBox.Show("successfully inserted");
}
else 
{
MessageBox.Show("not inserted");
}
```

This gives an error as:

> Can not implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'